# Poker game notation PGN as in chess

Tags: poker-tools

Is there a notation for poker hands, as in `PGN` for chess? If not can you suggest one.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no official notation quite like PGN for chess that is used for poker hands. However, there is multiple ways of sharing hands. If you are looking to show a specific hand to other players, you can use replay services like sharemypair.com that create a replay of the hand for others to watch. There is also a notation that is used by poker tracking software and poker sites to save hands that have already been played to a database locally, but this notation can vary across different services.

I think a universal notation would be a great idea, but as of now I don't think there is one.